# Include joined count of records + populated records into sequelize findById

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do:

```
User.findByPk(id, {
    attributes: {
        include: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("friends.id")), "friendsCount"]],
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        as: 'friends',
        required: false,
      }
    ]
  })
```

It works but when I select `friendsCount` field it only takes 1 row from friends (because of grouping and aggregation, I guess)

But I need to return also ALL ROWS for friends (which has `User.hasMany(User, { through: Friend })` relation).

Please help me to have both rows and count for user friends.

Thanks

Comment: `Seqeulize.literal` with subquery will help you to do it

Comment: @Anatoly in what section? Also, it would be nice it to go through ORM (not just like duplicate whole join part)

Comment: The same place, in `attributes`. Sequelize is not about complex queries with aggregate functions. Don't expect too much from it. It is more about simplifying CRUD operations and not thinking each time about plain SQL queries. Sure, it supports associations, hooks and so on but it does not try to replace all SQL features and its flexibility.

Comment: Well.. yeah.. that works for sure (it's not how I expected this to be... I was gonna hide all the stuff under model definition and not to expose this logic to controllers). Thanks a lot for the guidance!